# Where are some good places to reach great Django developers?

Tags: python, django

Are there communities where expert Django developers (ideally looking for jobs) like to hang out? Stackoverflow excluded :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://djangopeople.net/

Answer (score 3):

I'm partial to the #django channel on Freenode's IRC server. A few big names in the Django community hang around there. ( irc://irc.freenode.net/#django since SO's Markdown processor doesn't like irc:// in URLs)

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout [djangogigs](http://djangogigs.com/). And hang out on #django and #django-dev on freenode.